# Exposing CentOS 7 virtual machine to the internet?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

How do I expose the VM on the internet, I want to try installing a self-signed certificate on my website and try some basic pentesting on it. The VM is currently installed on my laptop and I'm using wifi

Comment: The keyword is port forwarding. But there won't be a step by step solution here.

Comment: Is it possible by bridging network? I haven't tried port forwarding

Comment: @davidbaumann I got it now it is possible by bridging network